# Forcing Wix to go do a download page for a required component

Tags: wix

When I build an MSI in Visual Studio, I have the option of specifying required components (in this case, MSXML6), and if the component isn't installed then the installer would say that it was needed, and would open a browser to the download site for the component.

How can I implement this using Wix?

(Note that I don't necessarily want it to install the component, just exit the installation and go to the download page.  I'm not trying to execute MSI from within MSI.)

Comment: OK I managed to figure this one out... after a lot of pain. See my blog post at <a href="http://cticoder.wordpress.com/2009/10/24/simulating-vs-nets-msi-installurl-property-with-wix/">CTICoder</a>

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to exit the installation?  We warn about missing required external components at install, then check at application startup & disable functions requiring them.  Our unattended batch services do the same startup check and log an error if not found, then exit gracefully.

Comment: I'm trying to get the Wix install package to function essentially the same as the VS installer, which did exit the installation and opened a browser to a URL specified in the MSI.  So yes, I would like the MSI to exit if the comoponent isn't already installed.